# Bookmarking in Notepad++ using input file

Tags: notepad++

This has probably been asked before, but I have a list of 50+ job names that I need to remove from a different file containing thousands of lines in. What i'd like to do is use my list of 50 jobs as an input source and automatically bookmark or remove lines from the other file.

I am super new to using Notepad++ for anything other than basic text editor stuff so if this is possible, then an "as basic as possible" explanation would be appreciated.

I know there's python plugins, i've seen grep thrown around too. I don't know what grep is, so I definitely don't know how to use that.

Any help would be appreciated
Thanks

Comment: It will be much more efficient to write a script in your favorite scripting language.

Comment: I wouldn't even know where to begin with that. The only scripting skill I have is VBA which is no doubt incredibly out of touch for this type of thing